# Do I have to declare placeholder on my reusable input in React with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a React components library with Typescript and have a question. Do I have to declare every single input properties in type/interface when creating a reusable component?

I have an input field created with styled components like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import { StyledInput } from './styles';

interface Props {
  type?: 'text' | 'password' | 'number' | 'tel' | 'time';
  name: string;
}

const Input: React.FC<Props> = ({ type = 'text', name, ...rest }) => {
  return <StyledInput type={type} name={name} {...rest} />;
};

export default Input;
```

I'm trying to use this  with placeholder, for example. Typescript throws this error:

```
Type '{ name: string; placeholder: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

As placeholder is intrinsic Input property, I thought it was resolved when I spread props `{...rest}`. Input doesn't already knows that placeholder is a string prop? Or onChange is a function, or onFocus?

Let me know if this question doesn't make any sense.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be explicit when declaring the types. Spreading the props `{...rest}` doesn't resolve the types for the custom `Input` component.

```js
interface IProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> {
   // type any custom props you want to pass other than-
   // existing props for a input like "placeholder", "name" or "type"
}
```

`React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>` will include types for all the default attributes that can be passed to a input element. But if you want the custom `Input` component to receive some other custom props as well you have to declare the type for it in the interface.